# Can FTPing to Google Cloud trigger pub/sub / cloud function?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, ftp, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Super random question.

Can a device that uses FTP, send a file up to google cloud, and then have that trigger a pub/sub or cloud function, without having to run a compute engine?

thanks team

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @nzmattman Do you mean, you want to send a file to Google Cloud Storage bucket just using Cloud Function through FTP from a device?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl well it is, if it is possible, then it leads its self to be a programming question...

Comment: @JMGelilio we only have ftp option, i don't really want to continue to support a single server just to have ftp to then process data with a cloud function

Comment: It seems not possible  because Cloud Storage doesn't have IP address and FTP requires IP address or domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file need to land into GCS. If your device can do only FTP, you need a FTP server on a compute engine to get the file and to store in in GCS.

Then, when the file is uploaded to GCS, a PubSub message is sent ([GCS notification to pubsub](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications)) and you can plug a Cloud Function on it.

Comment: ok cool, I thought it would be like that.  I was hoping there might be straight FTP directly to storage bucket, rather than having to use a compute engine to use as the ftp middleman

Comment: With some customers who absolutely don't want to manage VM and FTP server (patch and so on) by themselves, we use the FTP managed service by AWS and we then route the files to GCS. I don't like this design but it works!